# Modify a bitcode enabled IPA to load a framework or dylib

Tags: ios, bitcode

I have only a bitcode enabled IPA from a user and I need to modify the IPA such that it will load a framework or dylib and execute code from that dylib. Articles I read online talk about importing frameworks while working on the source code in Xcode IDE.

I only have the exported file, which is the IPA file. I know I can insert instructions into the bitcode files, but how do I make it load a framework or dylib that was not included in the original IPA in the first place?

I looked at the readable form of the bitcode files that were extracted and it seems that it is not so straightforward such as inserting instructions to call dlopen etc?

Is bitcode modification the best way to do this or can this be done by some linking process?